# Does macOS store the tags of Finder separately from the tagged files?

Tags: finder-tag

I just recovered data from a thumbdrive using Disk Drill following [What to do when mounting APFS from thumbdrive suddenly shows error and Disk Utility First Aid unable to fix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/440819/what-to-do-when-mounting-apfs-from-thumbdrive-suddenly-shows-error-and-disk-util)

But now all the Finder tags on all the recovered files are missing.

I tagged those files in the thumbdrive using my Macbook A1990 on a macOS 10.13.6. Does the OS store the tags separately (eg. in an SQLite database) so I can recover those tags? If yes, where may I find them? (If no, is there any other way to recover those tags, with Disk Drill, or otherwise?)

Answer (score 1):

The tags are in metadata associated with each original file - this even works across to a Windows shared folder structure, though Windows itself cannot see them.

If you're scavenging to rescue from a failed drive [especially if it's not HFS+], then you're lucky if you get the right file names, forget the metadata.

From your linked question, I wouldn't use APFS on a USB stick/SD card either. Stick to HFS+.

Comment: really sorry, I dun understand your answer completely. So by saying "then you're lucky if you get the right file names, forget the metadata." do you mean that I cannot retrieve back the metadata and hence also cannot retrieve back the tags?

Comment: See my comments below the other answer. DD doesn't make any kind of priority for retrieving meta or other ancillary data. It tries its best to find the file names but often doesn't even manage that. It all depends on how much of the original directory structure it can find. The more damage there is to the directory, the less chance it will find names/metadata. In my experiment below, I of course cannot reproduce your exact damage for comparison.